# Delegate methood not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, xcode6

I am not sure why my delegate method not being called. below is my code .Please tell me where i have made a mistake.
I have made all the set up correctly and i am sure i have made a silly mistake.my delegate method not being called. Any help will be greatly appreciated

**LSFiveViewController.h**

```
    @protocol OneToOne;
    @protocol OneToOne <NSObject>
    @optional
    -(void)dismissPopOverlsfive;
    @end

    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "AppDelegate.h"
    #import "TimeTableViewController.h"


    @class TimeTableViewController;

    @interface LearningSessionFiveDetailsViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
    {
        NSString *bookingString;
    }

    @property(nonatomic,weak)id<OneToOne>OneToOne;

    @end


**LSFiveViewController.m**


    @synthesize sessionAndDateLabelObj,OneToOne

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {

        [super viewDidLoad];

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    - (IBAction)BookSingleSessionAction:(id)sender
    {


    if (self.OneToOne && [self.OneToOne respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissPopOverlsfive)])
        {
            [self.OneToOne dismissPopOverlsfive];
        }

    }

    @end
```

**TimeTableViewController.h**

```
#import "OneToOneViewController.h"
#import "LearningSessionFiveDetailsViewController.h"
//other codes

@property(nonatomic,strong)LearningSessionFiveDetailsViewController *LSFiveObj;

@end
```

**TimeTableViewController.m**

```
#import "TimeTableViewController.h"

#import "LearningSessionFiveViewController.h"
#import "UIAlertView+Blocks.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 LSFiveObj=[[LearningSessionFiveDetailsViewController alloc]init];
    self.learnSearchFiveClassObj.OneToOne=self;
}

-(void)dismissPopOverlsfive
{
   This method is not being called

}
```

Comment: Did you use `setDelegate:` anywhere?

Comment: self.learnSearchFiveClassObj.OneToOne=self;
  this part of code will work as Set delegate

Comment: Try to add :`< OneToOne >` to `TimeTableViewController`. Try to check which one of your to tests in the "if" is at NO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Put this

```
self.LSFiveObj.OneToOne=self;
```

Instead of

```
self.learnSearchFiveClassObj.OneToOne=self;
```

and add `OneToOne` Protocol in your class

Comment: Can you tell me that are you using Storyboard or Xib?
If Storyboard then you are initializing viewcontroller instance wrong.
use this 
LSFiveObj = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboard id"];

Answer (score 1):

This line here:

```
self.learnSearchFiveClassObj.OneToOne=self;
```

should be

```
self.LSFiveObj.OneToOne=self;
```

In general property names should not start with a capital letter, thats only for classes.